# Do these sentences mean the same thing? Are thet grammatically correct? And if they mean different things what do they mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I'm sorry I haven't responded to your emails yet. I will respond to them as soon as possible.

Do the sentences given below mean the same thing as the sentence above? And are they all grammatically correct?

1. I'm sorry I haven't responded to your emails yet. I will **get back to you on those (emails)** as soon as possible.
2. I'm sorry I haven't responded to your emails yet. I will **get back to you on that one** as soon as possible.
3. I'm sorry I haven't responded to your emails yet. I will **get back to you with those emails** as soon as possible.

And if these sentences mean different things, what do they mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all have the same meaning, or almost the same. The differences are more in naturalness.

Number 1 is, I think, quite natural, but I prefer *about* to *on* (some may find this causes a slight meaning shift). Number 2 is also possible, but some people might find *that one* slightly odd. *That one* has to be understood as referring to *that matter* (or issue, problem, circumstance), but the matter has not been explicitly mentioned, which is the cause of the slight oddness. Number 3 is slightly odd because it refers to the response e-mails ("those e-mails") which a) do not yet exist and b) have not yet been explicitly mentioned.

My preferred locution would simply be *I'll get back to you as soon as possible*.